# Setup Network with two ISP

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, switch, linux-networking

Currently I have a network with 1 ISP, a router/modem, Gigabyte Switch and a server.

All the clients PC are automatically assign IP from DHCP server from a `Router/Modem A`.

`Server A` have a fixed IP (eg: 192.168.1.50), installed Linux - used for a Web Server, Asterisk, and Backup use.

I need a new second ISP with separate modem but I want `Server B` (eg: 192.168.1.60) use `ISP B` network only. For example if I download anything or use SIP (Asterisk) from `Server B` - It will use `ISP B` connection and not other ISP connections.  Also any clients PC should be able access to `Server A` (192.168.1.50) or `Server B` (192.168.1.60)

How can it be done? See example design below I think it might work?

Server B have two Ethernet Ports (One for Modem/Router and other connected a switch)

[image]

Comment: If you want to go the appliance route, try [something like this](http://serverfault.com/a/401683/13325).

Comment: @ewwhite Nah I don't want that.

Comment: Then static routes.

Comment: @ewwhite Please post answer if you can - how can it be done and is my network design is correct.

Comment: Looks correct... Make sure the default gateway on Server B points to the ISP.

Comment: @ewwhite I am glad to hear that. I am just concern how will the clients can access to Server B because all the Clients PC's are assigned with `Router/Modem A`. Oh also all the clients PC should use ISP A for internet only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup `Server B` as usual (pppoe/dhcp to `ISP B` via `Router/Modem B`) and configure the second NIC (that is facing the `Switch`) with a static IP address, OR you can configure that 2nd nic with DHCP as well but take care not to configure the `Router/Modem A` as gateway.

With `dhcpcd(8)` you can to this with `--nogateway` or with `dhclient(8)`, remove the `routers` from the parameters of the `request` clause in `dhclient.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can clients can access to Server A (web server) and Server B (web server) even all the clients PC IP are assigned from `Router/Modem A` gateway. All the clients PC are Windows OS

Comment: Sure, they are within the same Layer2 subnet, no router blocks their communication.