# Guide for using multiple consumer grade DSL

Tags: linux, routing, adsl, multi-homed

Consumer grade DSLs are way cheaper than getting at leased line, so for my building complex I am considering getting a bunch of DSLs instead of a leased line.

I feel confident that I am not the first to do that, so I am wondering if there is a Linux router that will somehow distribute the traffic over these DSLs. We are not talking about real bundling as the ISP should not be required to do anything.

My initial ideas are along the lines of computing a hash based on sender IP and recipient C-class and based on this hash choose the DSL, so all packets between a given client and server will always take the same DSL. And if a DSL goes down it should of course not be chosen.

But as I said: I cannot be the first to do this, so I feel confident there is a tested way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a solution here:

http://www.peplink.com/knowledgebase/balance-one-and-the-5-wan-license/

It gives 5 wan links, and 400 Mbps is plenty for my use.

Finally the price seems reasonable. [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B011VDJWSA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011VDJWSA)

Answer (score 0):

This is ridiculous.

When you lead the question with making an ill-informed decision to save up-front costs, it shows that you're not considering the big picture.

Do the right thing and get a network ISP appropriate for the organization.

Consumer class DSL is *almost never* the right option for a business and comes with limitations on performance, latency, support and overall SLA. Considering that multiple DSL lines from one provider will also use the same copper infrastructure, you'll gain no benefits in resiliency or throughput.

As to the question about leveraging multiple ISPs, yes, there are products and solutions that can accomplish that. Google "link balancer" for options. The [Elfiq link balancer](https://serverfault.com/questions/401661/multi-wan-bonding-across-different-media/401683#401683) is a well-equipped solution.

Most modern firewalls can also handle multiple ISP uplinks (see: "dual WAN").

Comment: It depends on his case. I have experienced situations where "business" service was more costly and had less features than home service. For example, checking and resetting the connection could only be done on business hours (Mo-Fr 8:00-20:00) for a business account, while consumers enjoy 24/7 support hotlines and immediate reaction (same provider, same location, just stupid money-grabbing policy on the provider end).

Comment: Then more details are needed about the specific situation. But in any major city, DSL is usually bad news.

Comment: I believe you are not considering the big picture: No where does it say anything about business. Also you are probably answering this as if you expect this to be installed in a developed nation and that your reference to "any major city" really is a reference to "any major city IN A DEVELOPED NATION". Get the big picture: Not everyone is in a city in a developed nation.

Comment: @OleTange It's not my problem that you didn't provide details about your situation.

Comment: @ewwhite OK, you really baffle me here: I am asking about the general case. You then go on your own and assume this is for a very specific case, for which you believe there is a better solution. How can that be "not providing enough details"? What should I have asked so that you would know that I am asking about the general case and not the very specific case you happen to have in mind?